# Launch an app with python on Pepper's tablet

Tags: python, kotlin, nao-robot, pepper

We have a Pepper robot that is running NAOqi version 2.5.10.7, and we have already installed our app. However, we are unable to open it. We had to use the cloud to install the app because adb didn't work, and now the loadApplication() method of ALTabletService isn't opening the app. How can we fix this?

loadApplication() doesn't work and adb doesn't work.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: how to ask a good question:
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)